# How to install 'OneDrive for Business' when offline (behind proxy)?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation, onedrive-for-business

I have downloaded OneDrive for Business from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2903984

The installation fails with something like "no diskspace left or no internet connection" (500+ GB free). I am however using the internet, because my browsers are configured to use the companies proxy servers (auth req).

Is there are kind "restributable" installer available for OneDrive for Business? Or maybe I could just go with SkyDrive Pro which still has a MSI installer. However, I do not know where to download from... ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Microsoft doesn't provide you an offline installer for OneDrive for Business. You could use this way http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2904296/en-us

Comment: Please add to your answer a brief summary of the steps outlined in the link provided. Link-only answers are less useful because links break over time. Thanks and welcome to SPSE.

Comment: @Phil not sure Thuan has to do this. His answer is valid and he is referencing a possible untested solution as a workaround he is not suggesting.

Comment: Sad, but true. :-( Any idea if the old SkyDrive Pro installer is still available somewhere for download? Couldn't find anything so far.